# How to count the repetition of values in an object in Java?

Tags: java, count, hashmap

I am trying to group the content of a list of object based on the value of one of its variables.

I am receiving a list that contains files. Each file is linked to an office and their presta attribute (int). I am then trying to classify these files depending on their office, and for each of these offices, check how many files used.

I have read online that maps, or hash maps can use the count function, but no matter how much I try I cannot understand how to use it properly. I am unable to modify the database, or to directly query the database to get this information and have to use Java to sort them properly.

```
public class Office {
    public String nameOffice;
    public int nbFiles; //total number of files
    public int nbFilesPrestaWeb; //files with a presta value of 4
    public int nbFilesPresta; //files with a presta value of 1
    public int nbFilesPrestaLight; //files with a presta value of 3
    public int nbFilesPaper; //files with a presta value of null
    // files with a presta value of 2 are obsolete  and are no longer active. They shouldn't show up
}

public class nameOffices{
    int idOffice;
    String nameOffice
}

public class File{
    public int id;
    public int idOffice;
    public int presta;
}
```

list of files containing

```
{
    {488858, 12, 4},
    {488859, 12, 4},
    {488860, 12, 3},
    {488861, 12, 3},
    {488862, 12, 1},
    {488863, 12, 4},
    {488864, 12, 4},
    {488865, 15, 3},
    {488866, 15, 3},
    {488867, 15, 1},
    {488868, 15, 4},
    {488869, 15, null},
    {488870, 15, null},
    {488871, 15, 3},
    {488872, 15, 1},
}
```

list of nameOffices

```
{
    {12, Paris},
    {15, Bruxelles},
}
```

and the result should end up as a list of Offices

```
{
    //name,tot,pw,p ,pl, paper 
    {Paris, 7 , 4, 1, 2, 0}
    {Bruxelles, 8 , 1, 2, 3, 2}
}
```

Comment: Do you should make it in a stream or you have all data and it needs only collect information into Office class ?

Comment: You have some issues with your datastructure here. `File` has a member `presta` which can contain `null`. If that is the case then you can't have it as primitive type, you have to store it as an object. `public Integer presta;` Also How will you will populate nameOffices datastructure.

Comment: Thankk you for the answers. I'll be careful with the integer. The info for the nameOffices are taken from the database as well. I tried to separate the informations depending on the different tables that are taken from the database. Unfortunately, I don't really have access to these data, and they are not properly linked with primary/foreign keys. So the least bad way that have been found by my coworkers was to load the tables they need and manually link them with each others.